# can someone explain this to me

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Times

Refers to the start + stop date

For each user assigned to a timeslice, **create a reference record** here of UserId + Time. What does the bolded mean? I know this is a noob question, sorry.

Comment: 1) This doesn't really have anything to do with c# or MVC, 2) I presume it means a database entry or some such, and 3) Is this homework?

Comment: No, it's actually not homework. It's a task which I cant tackle for my project. I have everything but to achieve what I need in order to complete this I couldnt make anything out of it, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about how to create a db schema for this:

```
ScheduleTimes 
===============
ScheduleTimesID  <-- PK
StartDate
StopDate

ScheduleUsers
===============
ScheduleUsersID  <-- PK
UserID           <-- FK to Users table
ScheduleTimesID  <-- FK to ScheduleTimes table

Users
=======
UserID           <-- PK
Username
...
```